# HEAD on next commit after git reset --hard <commit id>

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have a repo with some commits after a commit id 7348830
The immediate next commit has id aff68a1 (and there are more commits after that).

I am trying to revert the repo so that I get the files as they were AFTER commit 7348830

I did this:

`git reset --hard 7348830`

Followed by:

`git push -f origin master`

I was expecting to see the commit 7348830 as the latest commit in commit history. But I see commit aff68a1 on top.

Chk screenshot:

[image]

Is there an explanation as to why is this happening?

EDIT:
Here is the screenshot where I am making the reset:
[image]

I am pushing the code to bitbucket. And the list of commits there shows the other commit on top.
However my local git log shows me that commit id 7348830 is the latest one.

Git push shows everything upto date.

So can I assume its an issue with bitbucket itself(and not my git workflow)?

Comment: Did you get any message after the push command?

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink chk edits

Comment: The steps you took seem to be correct. You had no errors during the push right? (not just the reset command).
What does this return: `git fetch && git rev-parse origin/master`? It should return 7348830

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink this should not change files locally?

Comment: it returns 7348830 @Jonathan.Brink

Comment: Everything you say seems to be correct. Perhaps it's a bug in the bitbucket UI. I can't think of anything else that could be the culprit

Comment: ok thanks @Jonathan.Brink I have raised an issue with their support. Hoping for a solution soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HEAD on bitbucket webpage is same as local after force push.**

Please double check with below aspects:

1. In bitbucket commits page, please make sure you select `master` branch **not All branches**. Since the commits `7348830` and `aff68a1` may not on the same branch.

   [image] 
   [image]
2. Make sure you used `git push` with `-f` option after `git reset --hard 7348830`.
3. You can use `git status` to confirm your local `master` branch is `up-to-date with 'origin/master'`.

Comment: Yes this was the case with me. I was seeing commits from all branches.Thanks!